# How to import existent OpenSSL signed certificate to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I'm new to Tomcat SSL, now i have one certificate from someone which is signed with openssl, the files included as following:

```
ca.csr --server CSR
ca.key --root private key
cert.crt    --server certificate
root.crt --root certificate
```

Basically i want to know how could i import the openssl certificate to my Tomcat7 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert from OpenSSL's PEM format into DER, and then put the certificates into a keystore. You'll also need the certificate's key. You can see how to import a key and certificate here:

```
http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html
```

Just repeat the certificate procedure for each certificate. Also remember that you want to use "-alias tomcat" for the certificate that you want to have Tomcat use as your server's certificate (cert.crt).

You will not need the CSR for anything at this point: it was only used to get the certificate authority (CA) to issue a certificate to you.

Comment: But i don't have a private key for the cert.crt(Tomcat server certificate),how should i do?

Comment: Oh, is this self-signed root certificate? If so, where is the key that was used to generate the CSR for the cert.crt?

Comment: let me explain in more detail. The cert.crt is generated by openssl this way: openssl ca -config <work directory>\openssl.conf -out <work directory>\cert.crt -infiles <work directory>\ca.csr.   So could i generate a new server certificate and sign it with root.crt to replace the current cert.crt?

Comment: Yes, that would be the right way to do it. I don't know any other way to load the private part of the certificate without having the key. Perhaps you used the ca.key file to create the cert.crt file?

Comment: Ok. It's done now. I just create a new server certificate and let it to be signed with root.crt.

Comment: If were willing to start-over, you could have followed the instructions on the Tomcat SSL HOWTO.